# Customized datasource for TTMessageController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, three20

Hello good morning everyone, I am trying to use `TTMessageController` - but with a customized datasource.

I am trying lo load some data pulled from a server, which is in turned parsed using XML parser which is done in a background thread. So I am using `TTCatalog` example and here from the mockup datasource I have this:

**TestDatasource.m**

```
- (void)fakeSearch:(NSString *)text {
  self.names = [NSMutableArray array];
  // arrXML = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  if (text.length) {
    if (text.length > 1) {
      Parseobj *objParseobj = [[Parseobj alloc] init]; 
      [Parseobj getUpdate:[text lowercaseString]]; // This is done in a background thread
    }
  }
}
```

My question is how can I wait for the Thread to be completed so that it can populate the array once all data have been loaded from the server?

Many thanks for your usual and kind cooperation.

Comment: I see a few issues with this code already. You're instantiating `ParseObj` but not releasing it: `[objParseobj release];`. Where are you calling `- (void)fakeSearch:`?

Comment: Really need to see a bit more code in order to help.